# How to elegantly handle nil in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 4 values called `startStopId,startStopId1,endStopId,endStopId2`

I make query as shown below

```
sql = "select A.bus_id as busid, A.stop_id as source, A.arrival as atime, B.arrival as dtime from
(SELECT * from schedules as S where S.stop_id = #{startStopId}) A
inner join
(SELECT * from schedules as S where S.stop_id = #{endStopId}) B
on A.bustag = B.bustag
where A.arrival < B.arrival
and A.arrival > '#{@finalTime}'"

@possible_buses = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

There is a possibility that this query will return `nil`, in that case i will first try `startStopId`, `endStopId2`, and if that returns `nil` i will try another combo of the 4 values I have.

I was wondering if there is a elegant way of doing this in  ruby. I was thinking i can put this query under a method and pass the different combinations. But i would appreciate if someone experienced with ruby can provide an approach.

Comment: What do your models look like?

Comment: What do you mean by that? Do you want to know what fields i have?

Comment: You're using ActiveRecord, so I thought you might have some models and their relationships defined.

Comment: Could you write an english sentence explaining what you're doing ? Easier to translate english -> Ruby for me :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, I would pick more expressive variable names because I am not sure what exactly each one represents.

> There is a possibility that this query will return nil

This sounds like a great case for the Null Object Pattern. Essentially, whatever is returned from your query can be passed to the constructor of a class. That class can then determine what ought to be returned, whether it's simply the value of the query, or if the value of the query is `nil`, some predetermined value is returned. Employing this pattern usually means having a class such as `NullBusID` that represents, well, nothing.

For more on the Null Object Pattern:

http://confreaks.tv/videos/bathruby2015-nothing-is-something

https://robots.thoughtbot.com/rails-refactoring-example-introduce-null-object